# How to add multiple Data Contexts with UseSqlServer in start.cs

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Situation:  I have two diffent sql database to pull data.  When I inspect the connection from the two repositories, they are the same, even though they were initialized with different connection strings.
Startup.cs

```
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _config = configuration;
        _env = env;
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string connectionString1= _config.GetConnectionString("A_DbCoreConnectionString");
        services.AddDbContext<AContext>(options1 => options1.UseSqlServer(connectionString1)) ;
        string connectionString2= _config.GetConnectionString("B_DbCoreConnectionString");
        services.AddDbContext<BContext>(options1 => options1.UseSqlServer(connectionString2)) ;
    }
```

}

Controller.cs

```
  public MyController(IUserService userService,IARepository aRepository, IBRepository bRepository)
    {

        _userService = userService;

        _aRepository = aRepository;
        
        _bRepository = bRepository;
     }
        
    }
```

A and B repository.cs

```
 public class ARepository :IARepository
 {
    public AContext _dbContext; 
    public ARepository(AContext dbContext) 
    {
    _dbContext = dbContext;

    var connection=_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection(); 
    }
  ...
 }

 public class BRepository :IBRepository
 {
    public BContext _dbContext; 
    public BRepository(BContext dbContext) 
    {
    _dbContext = dbContext;
      var connection=_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
    }
    ...
 }
```

Comment: For the sake of testing, have you tried injecting the dbContext instances directly? Also, have you doublechecked that the connection strings are different in the configuration file?

Comment: The dependency injection does of the database context does not keep the connection string defined in AddDbContext is startup.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-development-part4/
Marinko Spasojevic said this code worked for him which is exactly the code pattern I followed.

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext 
{
public ProductContext(DbContextOptions<ProductContext> options)
: base(options)
{
}

public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
{
public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options)
: base(options)
{
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
 modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CompanyConfiguration());
 modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new EmployeeConfiguration());
}

public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"sqlConnection": "server=.; database=CompanyEmployee; Integrated Security=true",
"prodConnection": "server=.; database=ProdDb; Integrated Security=true"
},
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(opts =>
opts.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection"), b => 
b.MigrationsAssembly("CompanyEmployees")));

services.AddDbContext<ProductContext>(opts =>
opts.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("prodConnection"), b => 
b.MigrationsAssembly("CompanyEmployees")));
```

RepositoryManager (just a wrapper class for all my repo user classes provided with Context classes):

```
private RepositoryContext _repositoryContext;
private ProductContext _prodContext;

public RepositoryManager(RepositoryContext repositoryContext, ProductContext 
prodContext)
{
_repositoryContext = repositoryContext;
_prodContext = prodContext;
var conn = _repositoryContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
var prodConn = _prodContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
}
```